# What are some good writing analyzing software programs?

Tags: editing, software, tools, text-analysis, tone

What are some good writing analyzing software programs?

I'm on a trial right now of something called [EffectCheck](http://effectcheck.com) which seems to give you the overall tone of your work and provide charts and bar graphs of how heavy that is. For example, happiness vs anxiety. It also has suggestive words to replace certain tones.

Are there any other good programs out there? I'm curious to see how others may use these and what they find helpful (or lack thereof).

I'm looking for software that can pick up POV errors, passive voice, filters, overall tone of the work, odd wording. Not just a simple grammar checker and spell checker, but things that editors might look for.

Comment: What kinds of analysis do you want tools to provide?  Right now this question is both broad and more of an opinion survey, so I'm putting it on hold temporarily.  If you [edit] your question to include some criteria (what problem are you trying to solve?), it'll be reviewed for possible reopening.  Check out our short [tour] for more about what we're looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; that helps a lot.  I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 1):

https://prowritingaid.com is the best editing software I know of - artificial intelligence can't replace a human eye, but this does wonders to prepare your work before you show it to a human.

Comment: Could you [edit] to say a little more about what it does for you?  Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a sample analysis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOEoOXrpefw

Answer (score 1):

The [Writer's store](https://www.writersstore.com/) has a variety of software for writing support and analysis. I've used the **Writer's Dreamkit** (the more or less stripped down version of **Dramatica Pro**) and found it quite useful and insightful.

They have software targeted at other fields of writing as well, screenplay, scripts, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [AutoCrit](https://www.autocrit.com/). It is more expensive than some competitors (such as ProWritingAid that others mentioned), but from what I have read it more exhaustive and easier to understand. It does everything you would expect from software to analyze fiction.

Next, there is [Hemmingway](http://www.hemingwayapp.com/). I haven't done any serious work on it, but it is free which makes it a good option even if its reports aren't as good as AutoCrit's.

Finally, if you need some help wit grammar, [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) is a great tool.